# Docker: Java 8 installation failing on Ubuntu

Tags: java, docker, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install java 8 on base image of Ubuntu in a docker container.
I am running the following command,

```
RUN apt-get update && \ 
apt-get install -y software-properties-common python-software-properties && \ 
add-apt-repository "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main" && \ 
apt-get update && \ 
echo "$accept-license" | sudo debconf-set-selections && \ 
apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated -y oracle-java8-installer && \ 
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer
```

On running the above command I am getting the following error,

```
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.57.66.26|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-10-20 06:29:41 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

download failed

```
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Thank you,
Farhan

Comment: Why do not you use [official java image](https://hub.docker.com/_/java/)

Comment: or the openjdk image.

Comment: @BukharovSergey I am trying to do a POC in which I am required to prepare a dockerfile for java installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of this morning, the Webupd8 Oracle-java8-installer is successfully downloading and installing in docker for me. The links in the PPA installer must have been updated. Yay!

My Dockerfile that was failing at the end of last week but now works

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

USER root
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install default-jre
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common python-software-properties

RUN apt-get -y -q update && \
    apt-get -y -q upgrade && \
    apt-get -y -q install software-properties-common htop && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java && \
    apt-get -y -q update && \
    echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections && \
    apt-get -y -q install oracle-java8-installer && \
    update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle
```

Comment: can you please share the PPA link?

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java

Comment: To my answer, I added the portion of my Dockerfile that does the install.

Comment: Thanks @Ziska220, I tried with my docker file again. Was able to install java. :)

Comment: @Ziska220, with what you posted, do you still need to update environment variables? JAVA_HOME and PATH?

Comment: This works for me also. Thanks for sharing this.